# Update syntax of boolean value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried to update boolean values in MySql database but i receive error :

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add=0, edit=0, delete=0, view=1 where id=3' at line 1`

Table : tempemp

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `struts`.`tempemp`;
CREATE TABLE  `struts`.`tempemp` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`role` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`add` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`edit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`view` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Syntax : **"update tempemp set add=?,edit=?,delete=?,view=? where id=?";**

Comment: It's bad practise to use reserve words as column names, and will give you lots of extra hassle in the future.

Comment: Did you go out of your way to use MySQL keywords to name your columns?

Comment: @SteveSmith thanks.
next time i use proper column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backquotes to escape reserve word:

```
 update tempemp set `add`=0, `edit`=0, `delete`=0, `view`=1 where id=3;
```

Comment: Thanks @Forward for your opinion.

Comment: I search this error on many sites but can not found answer. only you(@Forward) solve this error.